# How to get the index of predicted wrong data in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am doing sentimental analysis and using keras to predict positive/negative of movie reviews.
What I want to know is the raw data, those are wrongly predicted by my model.
I only can get the accuracy, loss from my model but I want to get the subset of texts in which my model predicted wrong. How to do it?

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras
import numpy as np
import  gc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
dataset=pd.read_csv('balanced_dataset.csv')
tk=Tokenizer(num_words=2000)
tk.fit_on_texts(dataset.review)
x=tk.texts_to_matrix(dataset.review)
y=dataset.label

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=40)

model=keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8,input_dim=2000))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['acc'])

del tk
gc.collect()

result=model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=20,validation_split=0.1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply, use: [model.predict()](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict)

```python
pred = model.predict(x_test)
indices = [i for i,v in enumerate(pred) if pred[i]!=y_test[i]]
subset_of_wrongly_predicted = [x_test[i] for i in indices ]
```