# How to get the index of predicted wrong data using BERT embedder with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I have a dataset that contain three columns, first column is DOI of different articles ,second column is abstract of related articles and third column is label of each articles(0 or 1).

I used the below code to train and evaluate my model. I only can get the accuracy from my model but I want to get the DOI(index) of those data that predicted wrong.

```
processed_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: sorted_all, output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32)) 

BATCH_SIZE = 32

batched_dataset = processed_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes=((3,None),()))

NB_BATCHES = math.ceil(len(sorted_all) / BATCH_SIZE)   

NB_BATCHES_TEST = NB_BATCHES // 10   

batched_dataset.shuffle(NB_BATCHES)

test_dataset=  batched_dataset.take(NB_BATCHES_TEST)

train_dataset = batched_dataset.skip(NB_BATCHES_TEST)

text_model.fit(test_dataset, epochs=NB_EPOCHS)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49406526/14290681) answer your question ?