# Keras + TF | Export Validation Images which failed the classification for current Epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am fairly new to Keras + Tensorflow and apologize if this question is too basic.

I am training a model with 2 output classes. (Categorical crossentropy). The accuracy increases as expected every epoch until it plateaus.

I want to know that during model training, when Keras is using the validation data, is it possible to export details of the used files for validation and the assigned labels vs. expected labels for those images. I want to understand if some particular images are always misclassified by the model etc.

Even a pointer to such an API would be helpful.

I am looking for something like below

```
Epoch Number: 1, ValidationImages = FX1, AssignedLabel = 0, ExpectedLabel = 0
Epoch Number: 1, ValidationImages = FX2, AssignedLabel = 0, ExpectedLabel = 1
Epoch Number: 1, ValidationImages = FX1, AssignedLabel = 1, ExpectedLabel = 1
```

and so on... for each epoch.

P.S. My limitation is that at this stage I am in the phase of model selection and cannot afford to keep data isolated for a test set and run this exercise on it. It would be helpful if I can get more insights on the validation process to decide initial processing for images.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66144865/how-to-get-the-index-of-predicted-wrong-data-using-bert-embedder-with-keras/66149348#66149348 help ?

Comment: Thanks. It does seem to be an unanswered question till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps somebody. I found the solution via the callbacks in below article.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation

The idea is to utilize the epoch end function in the callback something like below.

```
class DisplayCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    show_predictions()
    print ('\nSample Prediction after epoch {}\n'.format(epoch+1))


EPOCHS = 20
VAL_SUBSPLITS = 5
VALIDATION_STEPS = info.splits['test'].num_examples//BATCH_SIZE//VAL_SUBSPLITS

model_history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=EPOCHS,
                          steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                          validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,
                          validation_data=test_dataset,
                          callbacks=[DisplayCallback()])
```

If someone needs details, I recommend going through the full code in the link as it is very clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but you could get a good insight by running model.predict on the validation set. This will show you which validation images the trained model misclassifies.

Comment: Thanks for this. This approach is doable inside callback for every epoch by any chance?

Comment: I think a custom callback could be constructed to do that . If I get a chance I will give it a try.